# Attaching javadoc to jar and link to Android Studio

Tags: jar, android-studio, javadoc

I have javadoc documentation written for a .jar library that I want the user to be able to see right after he imports our jar into a project. In eclipse, I was able to do this by adding a *libname.jar.properties* file that points to where my javadoc directory is. This way when I import my jar into a project in eclipse I would be able to see the javadoc documentation when I hover over one of the api methods in my library.

Basically, I want to be able to have the same functionality in Android studio. Any help would be appreciated.